# Social sharing plugin for Craft 3

Tags: plugin-social-login

Is there a social sharing plugin ready for Craft 3? There is no listing in the new plugin store nor do the V2 offer a revision.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the social media plugins I see on https://plugins.craftcms.com (which is the public version of the plugin store).

Sharing related:

- https://github.com/boscho87/facebook-connector
- https://github.com/Rias500/craft-notifications
- https://github.com/Rias500/craft-telegram-notification-channel

Integrations that don't appear to deal with sharing:

- https://github.com/bymayo/craft-dribbble
- https://github.com/dukt/facebook
- https://github.com/dukt/social
- https://github.com/dukt/social-github
- https://github.com/dukt/social-linkedin
- https://github.com/dukt/twitter

Comment: Thank you, Brad - I guess a specific plugin for Addthis or Sharethis isn't available.....